# java constructors with inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I am creating a copy of Tetris in order to practice game programming. I am using OpenGL in Java.

In Tetris, as most of you know, when a TetrisBlock is created, it starts at the top middle of the screen and for each second or so, translates down 1 unit of Y. When the block collides with the bottom edge OR another TetrisBlock, it is stored onto the grid and a new block is created, again from the top.

I have a parent class (TetrisBlock) and sub-classes (Z-Block, T-Block etc) which extend the parent class. The necessary snippets for each of these classes are in code below. For the following example, I will focus on the IBlock.

Parent Class:

```
public abstract class TetrisBlock implements KeyListener {

protected int[] myTranslation;

public TetrisBlock(int[] startingTranslation) {
    myTranslation = startingTranslation;
}
```

Sub Class:

```
public class IBlock extends TetrisBlock {

private static final int[] startingTranslation = { 5, -1 } //the top left of my screen is [0,0] so [5,-1] is the translation for I-Block to start in the top middle of the screen

public IBlock() {
    super(startingTranslation);
}
```

Now, when it is time for the block to move down 1 unit, and if it does not collide into anything, this part of the code is called within the same class.

```
myTranslation[1]--;
```

The problem lies here, when the block is constructed again in my main class, like follows:

```
currentBlock = new IBlock();
```

The new IBlock starting point is the translation of the previously created and collided IBlock, not the top middle of the screen. startingTranslation is static final and prints [5,-1], so that is not being changed. However, when new IBlock is called, myTranslation in the parent class is the previous IBlock's collided translation. I hope the issue lies within the information given. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, what you probably want to do is have each `TetrisBlock` track its own translation, and update that rather than creating a new block each time the block moves.

Comment: I believe each TetrisBlock does track and update its own translation. The issue is when the 2nd IBlock is created, it does not start from the top middle as TetrisBlocks are supposed to. Rather it starts in the exact same position as the 1st TetrisBlock. Is that what I am supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately (for you) `private static final int[] startingTranslation = { 5, -1 }` does not mean that the contents of the array can't be changed, i.e. it's not a read-only array. It just means that you can't assign a new array to it. The *array* is final, the ints inside it aren't, so what you're doing is using the reference to the original array which gets changed as your block drops.

You want to make a defensive copy of your array with for example `clone()`, so the original array isn't changed.

```
super(startingTranslation.clone());
```

Comment: Ohh, I didn't know that. That makes sense. Thanks, this solves my problem! :)